# Open GCP console UI using gcloud cli

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there a way to login to the GCP console UI with the current available credentials using the `gcloud` cli? In AWS it's possible, but I don't see an obvious way with GCP.

Answer (score -1):

No. Doing so would be a security vulnerability. Your access to Google Cloud is via Google Accounts. Google Accounts is used for many services (Pay, YouTube, etc). The credentials that the CLI obtained are stored in a file. If you could authenticate the browser (Google Accounts) from the CLI credentials, your account could be stolen or impersonated. Therefore, that is not possible.

The credentials for the CLI `gcloud` are from an authentication process using a browser (except for service accounts) that you did with the command `gcloud auth login`. The CLI will launch the browser, but authentication is managed by the browser and not the CLI. The CLI fetches credentials from an HTTP callback that the browser initiates.